# A Question on Integrating Non-Integer Powers of Cosine

Tags: analysis

I've just learned Residue Theorem and some tricks regarding evaluating real integrals using residues of rational functions on unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$. However, I have wondered whether there are similar tricks for integrals of the type $ \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos ^n(x)\,dx $  for non-integer, rational n. My question specifically regards the Residue theorem, but any other methods are also appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to derive
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^\alpha(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\sqrt\pi}2\cdot\frac{\Gamma(\frac12(\alpha+1))}{\Gamma(\frac12\alpha+1)},\quad \alpha>-1
$$
(or $\operatorname{Re}\alpha>-1$).

One way is to evaluate $\iint_{x,y>0} x^\alpha e^{-x^2-y^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y$ in two different ways and compare the results.